# Stata odbc query with spaces in the column names

Tags: stata

I am trying to execute a sql query from within stata, over ODBC.  Some of the column names have spaces in them.

Stata wants to replace the spaces with underscores, which does not work.  If i tried escaping the spaces, escape-quoting the column name, none of which seem to work.

In the below example the column name is "Program Type Code".

```
odbc load, exec("SELECT ReportEffectiveDate, Program_Type_Code, CWIN FROM 
McDreamIndvReport WHERE ReportEffectiveDate > '20140701' and     
ReportEffectiveDate<'20150801'") dsn("HSAReports")
```

Other stata odbc commands seem to allow you to quote tables or columns with spaces in them, but exec expects a quoted string, and escaping the quotes (\"Program Type Code\") is not working.

Any suggestions?

thanks!

Comment: Spaces are illegal in Stata variable names so it will automatically replace spaces with an underscore. In terms of reading the table into Stata using `odbc load, exec`, you might try adding square brackets (`[` and `]`) around the column name

Comment: Yes, the brackets worked great - exactly what I was looking for, thanks!  If you write it as an answer I can mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces are illegal in Stata variable names so those will be replaced with an underscore when you read in data from an ODBC link regardless, but to read the data in if the ODBC source table has spaces in the column names, you can add square brackets (`[` and `]`) around the name with spaces.

In your example, that would be:

```
#delimit ;
odbc load, exec("SELECT ReportEffectiveDate, [Program Type Code], CWIN 
  FROM McDreamIndvReport 
  WHERE ReportEffectiveDate > '20140701' and ReportEffectiveDate<'20150801'") 
dsn("HSAReports");
```